# How to Fetch data in Descending order in Laravel 5.6 using provider

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, sorting, laravel-5.6

I'm fetch data from database using App\Provider ad show data in home page and admin panel. I want to sort data in descending order. 
Code in app\provider

```
View::composer('*',function($view){
        $view->with('services', Service::all());
    });
```

Comment: I suggest you should review and learn what laravel provides by reading framework files. You will see a lot of things and learn quickly. e.g. if you see `your_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php` you will find function `latest` and many more. Best of luck.

Comment: yeah sure i'll read and learn more Thank you for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort data in Descending and Acesending order in Laravel 5.6 it just simple code like this:

```
View::composer('*',function($view){
        $view->with('services', Service::latest()->get());
    });
```

Latest function is equal `orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');` and get function help to get all data from database. 
This code also use `('services', Service::latest()->get())` fetch data in descending order in controller.
Thank You
if you have any question you can ask me feel free.

Comment: `latest` is `orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')` when no column is passed